# How get the cost price?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, finance

I have the following spreadsheet:

[image: Spreadsheet]

For column B, the formula is simple: B1 + (B1 * A2)

The question is: how to get the numbers in column C?

I manually typed all values on column C but the idea is if I type 24200 on C1, it calculates all the other values.

24200 - 10% = 21780

21780 is 220 less than the initial price of 22000.

I think that a better question is:

**If I replace all values between lines 2 and 11 by X so**

**X + 1% = 24200,
X + 2% = 24200,
X + 3% = 24200?**

**How to calculate X for each line on column C?**

Thank you.

Comment: They are the same numbers in column two but in reverse order.

Comment: Did you look at the equations in column C?  What did you find?

Comment: I know, because I used the same number as an example for both columns. What I want to know, is what is the mathematical formula to calculate the values on the column C.

Comment: It is this what you wanted?

Comment: So you want the formula to calculate the values you didn't give us in column C?  How could we have guessed?  Please think carefully about your question.  I don't understand the upvotes at all.

Answer (score 2):

One way is $C=46200-B$.  I am sure that is not what you are looking for, but it gets all the right numbers.

Added:  with your addition that you want to understand
$$X+3\%=24200$$
that should really be written
$$X+3\% \cdot X=1.03 \cdot X=24200\\
X=\frac {24200}{1.03}$$
Calculators will use the syntax $X+A\%$ to mean $X\cdot (1+\frac A{100})$.  It is not correct to write it that way.  If read properly, $X+A\%=X+\frac A{100}$, so $24200+3\%=24200.03$ which is not what you want.